# Recover databases from old WAMP directory

Tags: database, phpmyadmin, wamp

My computer had a meltdown and I was forced to backup my stuff and format the drive. I have a backup of my old Wamp directory and was wondering how I go about restoring the databases to my new Wamp installation?

I couldn't access my PC before the wipe, so I wasn't able to export the DBs, I only made a copy of the filesystem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution would be to do this.

Uninstall the new wampserver your installed, then manually delete the \wamp\ folder and all subfolders.

Copy the backup of the complete \wamp\ folder back to where it was originally ( exactly where is was, drive and folder )

Run \wamp\wampmanager.exe

Using the icon in the system tray do

```
wampmanager -> Apache -> Service -> Install service

wampmanager -> MySQL -> Service -> Install service
```

You should be back to where you were as of the time you did the backup using exactly the same versions of Apache and MySQL and have all you databases back in place along with MySQL userids and passwords.

Then all you have to do is recreate the WampServer icon on your desktop, thats the wampmanager.exe program

Answer (score 0):

Copy the whole folder 
`c:/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql-version`(from old wamp dir)
to `c:/wamp/bin/mysql/`. And refresh wamp server and there in the `wamp server menu->mysql>mysql version>` you will be able to see version of your old mysql click on that and open phpmyadmin. All your databases with tables will open.

I had the same issue and this worked for me.